# Perl pQuery not working

Tags: perl

I am having a very weird problem that i am hoping somebody can help me with.

We recently moved to a new CentOS server, and we had a bunch of Perl scrapers that stopped working.
While investigating the issue i found that the pQuery module is not working at all.

I wrote this little test script:

```
 use pQuery;
 use WWW::Mechanize;
 use Data::Dumper;

 my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
 $mech->get("http://google.com/search?q=pquery");
 $pquery = pQuery($mech->content);  

 print Dumper($pquery);
 exit;
```

On the new server this returns:

```
$VAR1 = bless( [], 'pQuery' );
```

This happens with any page I try to load into pQuery.
I tried updating the pQuery::DOM module, but I have the latest version installed.
Mechanize is returning content so i'm thinking the problem is with the pQuery module or one of it dependencies.

I'm baffled ! Any ideas or suggestions on how to get this resolved or suggestions on what I can do next to get more info on this issue would be really appreciated.

Comment: Works for me, check `$mech->status` to see what happens to your request.

Comment: What exact versions of perl, WWW::Mechanize and pQuery do you have installed (`perl -MFoo -E'say Foo->VERSION'`)? Are you behind a firewall or similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up upgrading perl 5.8 to 5.10 and that fixed the problem.